# Webform confirmation page with new information

Tags: webforms, forms

I'm in the process of building a form to add new ServiceDesk requests. Below is the process.

1. Create a webform
2. Write a submit handler function to Create work order (according to [ServiceDesk api](https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/help/adminguide/api/request-attributes.html#addreq), form data need to be submitted to http://machine_name:Port_Number/servlets/RequestServlet and a response in xml format displays "Success" message along with the WorkOrder ID. )
3. Display success or error message on the form results page.

**Work I have done so far:**

1. Created a webform
2. Wrote a submit handler function to Create work order (I tested and I'm able to add ServiceDesk requests). As the xml file with success/error message is shown on a different server (http://machine_name:Port_Number/servlets/RequestServlet), I'm unable to print the success/error message on the form confirmation page.

Please can anyone tell me how to display this info?

Thanks

Comment: What you are using for printing message? or Have you used webform default message after submission get succesfull?